# CSS Container Class

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am working through a web dev project on youtube building a JavaScript clock. I think I know that creating a container and a child element allows positioning with absolute and relative.

However I don't understand why `.clock` is in every line and for example where it says `.clock .number1` its not just `.number1`. Does the container or parent element have to be specified?

```css
.clock {
  background-color: red;
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 2px solid black;
  position: relative;
}

.clock .number {
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.clock .number1 {
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}

.clock .number2 {
  transform: rotate(60deg);
}

.clock .number3 {
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.clock .number4 {
  transform: rotate(120deg);
}

.clock .number5 {
  transform: rotate(150deg);
}

.clock .number6 {
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.clock .number7 {
  transform: rotate(210deg);
}

.clock .number8 {
  transform: rotate(240deg);
}

.clock .number9 {
  transform: rotate(270deg);
}

.clock .number10 {
  transform: rotate(300deg);
}

.clock .number11 {
  transform: rotate(330deg);
}

.hand .hour {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  top: 20px;
  left: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="clock">
  <div class="hand hour"></div>
  <div class="hand minute"></div>
  <div class="hand second"></div>
  <div class="number number1">1</div>
  <div class="number number2">2</div>
  <div class="number number3">3</div>
  <div class="number number4">4</div>
  <div class="number number5">5</div>
  <div class="number number6">6</div>
  <div class="number number7">7</div>
  <div class="number number8">8</div>
  <div class="number number9">9</div>
  <div class="number number10">10</div>
  <div class="number number11">11</div>
  <div class="number number12">12</div>
</div>
```

Comment: All `.clock` parts in all compound selectors can (and should) be removed. The rule of thumb is to create the least specific selector that does the job.

Comment: It's a way of using CSS element selection so that only the classes withing a parent element (.clock)  are selected. For example, you might have 2 clocks (.clock1 & .clock2) that have both have .numbers. By specifying .clock1 .numbers - you only apply the styles to .numbers on .clock1 and not all .numbers.

Comment: Could you please try and explain again @Gavin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer: you do not need the .clock in every line.

In CSS, when there are two classes specified, it will only target an object that has all of these classes. For example, let's say we have two things that have different parent elements but the same class name.

```
<div class="parent1">
     <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
<div class="parent2">
     <div class="thing"></div>
</div>
```

If we wanted to target only one of the child elements, it would become tricky since they both have the class "thing". So in this case, we would want to use two classes to identify a specific element:

```
.parent1 .thing {
     //insert styles
}
```

However, in your case, it appears that each element has a unique name, so there is no need to specify two classes. This was likely written in this way so that if there ever was an element created with the same class name, it wouldn't interfere with the already existing element.